# ¿tienen problemas en ssrs al imprimir un codigo de barras ya que no respeta el formato de codigo de barras?

Tags: ssrs

en mi reporte de ssrs genera un codigo de barras el problema es cuando lo mando a imprimir ya que me lo trasnforma en pdf y no me respeta el codigo de barras y lo pasa solo con numeros.
el servidor cuenta con la fuente de code39, y a maquina donde lo quiero imprimir tambien tiene la fuente.
este problema solo lo respeta cuando lo descargo pero en word. pero no estoy buscando eso quiero realizar que cuando de el click en imprimir lo genere sin problemas.
si alguien sabe como hacer o si se puede les agradezco gracias :)